# People Permission: View own unpublished content do not work

Tags: users

I want let anonymous user can visit unpublished content, So I enable `View own unpublished content` for anonymous user.

But I open other browser to visit the url of unpublished content. But it alert me:

**Access denied**

I clear the cache, but above problem again

So, It is a bug?

Comment: as it says `View OWN unpublished content` if the content is created by anonymous they can view it.

Comment: Did you rebuild the user permissions? Go here: admin/reports/status/rebuild

Comment: @NikhilM, Thanks, I got, But how to let anonymous to view every unpublished content?

Comment: Whats the point of keeping the content unpublished if its viewable by all users ?

Comment: I just want to build a REST api, I count data from other program(android). and no authentication.

Comment: okay what i might do is to save the content as authored by admin or a device user. that will be better for kind of sorting and filtering. have you tries @tyler.frankenstein s method ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Drupal 7
>
> In Drupal 7, users are not allowed to view any unpublished content by
>   default, not even content created by themselves. By enabling 'View own
>   unpublished content', you grant users access to their own unpublished
>   content.
>
> The only way to allow users access to all unpublished content in
>   Drupal 7 (without using a contributed module), is to enable the
>   permission 'Bypass content access control'. Use this permission with
>   extreme caution as it has far more consequences than just allowing
>   access to unpublished content. In combination with Organic Groups for
>   example, this permission allows access to private group content
>   regardless of whether the user is a group member.

https://drupal.org/node/1106606

On that page are some contributed modules to set permissions you need...